# Writing a input output for binary counting on fingers

Tags: binary, user-input

I very new to coding and trying to figure out how to make code where you input a number and it gives you the fingers needed to display it in binary (if unknown right thumb=1, right index=2 right middle=4 right ring=8 right pinky=16, left pinky=32 left ring=64 left middle=128 left index=256 left thumb=512 you alternate between fingers adding them together to produce numbers)

I tried looking here for input number output letter code here but when I plugged it in it would not function and I don't know enough to fix it.

```py
characters = 'abcdefghij'
d = {}
for x in range(len(characters)):
d[characters[x]] = x+1

print(d)
#prints {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 8, 'e': 16, 'f': 32, 'g': 64, 'h': 128, 'i': 256, 'j': 512}
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Which programming language are you using? Please add your code.

Comment: I trying to learn python, I should have probably tried tutorials before jumping in the deep end but here is the code I used

Comment: characters = 'abcdefghij'
d = {}
for x in range(len(characters)):
    d[characters[x]] = x+1

print(d)
prints {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 8, 'e': 16, 'f': 32, 'g': 64, 'h': 128, 'i': 256, 'j': 512}

Comment: Please add it to your question so it is readable.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this website I don't know how format code in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
def number_to_fingers(number):
    fingers = {
        'left_thumb': 512,
        'left_index': 256,
        'left_middle': 128,
        'left_ring': 64,
        'left_pinky': 32,
        'right_pinky': 16,
        'right_ring': 8,
        'right_middle': 4,
        'right_index': 2,
        'right_thumb': 1
    }

    finger_names = []
    for finger in fingers:
        if number >= fingers[finger]:
            finger_names.append(finger)
            number -= fingers[finger]

    return ", ".join(finger_names)

# Input the number you want to convert to finger names
input_number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
finger_names = number_to_fingers(input_number)
print(f"Output: {finger_names}")
```

First you map the fingers to their values in the dictionary `fingers`. The list `finger_names` will store your result. Then you iterate over `fingers`, for each finger checking whether the input number is greater than or equal to the value associated with that finger. If it is, the finger name is appended to `finger_names`, meaning this finger is needed for the binary representation. The value of the finger is then subtracted from the input number to keep track of the remaining value to be represented. In the end `", ".join(finger_names)` concatenates the finger names into a string so it will look prettier in the printed output.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-covert-decimal-to-binary-number/) are some nice examples for how to write python code that converts decimal number to binary.

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfectly and your explanation helped me understand it

Comment: You can accept the answer if it answers your question :)